# Campaign Related Contributions

Tags: civicontribute

When I search Contributions/Find Contributions and specify the current year date range and a specific campaign, I receive the following error "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: syntax error  Return to home page."  How do I get campaign related contributions?
I cannot reproduce this error on the Demo site. Seems to work fine there.
When I produce a Summary Contribution Report grouped by Campaign I receive what at first to be a valid Report showing Contributions by Campaign, when I open the Detail Report for the Campaign Contribution in question, it shows many Contributions totally unrelated to the Campaign.

Comment: Hi. Have you verified same issue on Demo?

Comment: I have and it works fine there. I have edited my original post with additional information.

Comment: We upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.10 from 4.6.8 and problem seems to be solved. We had recently migrated our site and perhaps this was the reason for the syntax error I had been receiving when searching for specific Campaign contributions.